# Why does Test Connection fail in Wildfly 20 Using SQL Anywhere sajdbc4 driver?

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, wildfly, driver, sybase

I had Wildfly 10 running previously and have just upgraded to Wildfly 20 (under Ubuntu 20). My configuration from Wildfly 10 no longer works when it comes to getting the Sybase SQL Anywhere 17 sajdbc4 driver working. When I "Test Connection" it fails. I am using the same configuration and testing against the exact same (SQL Anywhere High Availability) database server.

"Test Connection" on the following Datasource triggers an "Invalid ODBC handle" error:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/TestDB" pool-name="TestDB" spy="true" tracking="true" enlistment-trace="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlanywhere:Host=192.168.1.45:19000,192.168.1.45:19001;ServerName=TestDB</connection-url>
    <driver>sajdbc4.jar</driver>
             <security>
                <user-name>...</user-name>
                 <password>...</password>
             </security>
</datasource>
```

Connection is not valid

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid ODBC handle

```
at deployment.sajdbc4.jar//sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver.makeODBCConnection(Native Method)
at deployment.sajdbc4.jar//sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver.connect(IDriver.java:809)
at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
... 35 more
```

How I set this up:

1. I used the console to Deploy the sajdbc4.jar and that appears to work fine. I see no errors and sajdbc4 shows up as Deployed in the console and it also shows up as a JDBC Driver in the Subsystems. Here is what was created in standalone.xml after using the console:

   deployment name="sajdbc4.jar" runtime-name="sajdbc4.jar">
   content sha1="b690ff7a8ba1a3c2e8dd5079138b7970d969c2b9"/>
   /deployment>

(I had to drop the leading angle brackets to get the previous lines to show - even when marked as Code!)
Next I had to ensure that the java.library.path and classpath included the path to the sajdbc4.jar and its support files so Wildfly can find them. To do so I added the "HACK" to the following in standalone.conf:

```
if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
   # ADDED FOLLOWING HACK
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main -cp .:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main/sajdbc4.jar"
   echo "Java Properties Next:"
   java -XshowSettings:properties -version
else
   echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with values: $JAVA_OPTS"
fi
```

Finally, I added the datasource block shown at the top. After starting Wildfly TestDB shows up as a Datasource in the Datasources Subsystem but when I Test Connection I get the "Invalid ODBC handle" error.

I feel confident that the driver and all its support files are "working" because I have a very simple Java test app that just makes a connection to TestDB, fetches from a table and displays the rows. Note that it uses the exact same java.library.path and classpath as I set in standalone.conf:

```
cd $HOME/Desktop
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main
export CLASSPATH=.:/opt/wildfly-20.0.1.Final/modules/system/layers/base/com/sybase/main/sajdbc4.jar
java sajdbc4DriverTest.java
```

Note that server.log shows no errors and in fact shows lines like:

```
[org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "sajdbc4.jar" (runtime-name: "sajdbc4.jar")
...
[org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class sap.jdbc4.sqlanywhere.IDriver (version 4.0)
[org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = sajdbc4.jar
[org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/TestDB]
...
[org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "sajdbc4.jar" (runtime-name : "sajdbc4.jar")
```

Note that my connection string is for connecting to a SQL Anywhere High Availability system (hence the two URLS). In Wildfly 20 I see that there is now a new "HA URL Separator" field in the console's Datasource definition page. I tried setting that to a comma and that just changed the Test Connection error to "Unable to create connection from URL":

```
2020-08-25 11:45:08,378 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031085: Unable to create connection from URL: jdbc:sqlanywhere:Host=192.168.1.45:19000,192.168.1.45:19001;ServerName=TestDB
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getHALocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:381)
```

How do I get "Test Connection" to work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be related to the fact that I was running Wildfly as a service and apparently my efforts above to set the java.library.path is failing. I know the reason for the error but I do not know how to set the path when running as a service.